# Self-intersections of trigonometric polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $p(t) = a_0 + a_1 \cos(t)+ b_1 \sin(t) + a_2 \cos(2t) + b_2 \sin(2t)$ is a quadratic trig polynomial with complex coefficients.  Assume that $a_2$ and $b_2$ are not real multiples of the same number.  Is it true that $p(t)$ has at most finitely many self-intersections, that is, are there at most finitely many pairs $t_1, t_2 \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $p(t_1) = p(t_2)$ and $t_1 \neq t_2$?

Comment: Yes, use $\tan t/2$ to reduce to a rational function.

Comment: Hi Brian!  What does it mean that $a_2$ and $b_2$ are not real multiples of the same number?  For instance, $a_2/b_2$ is a real number unless $b_2 = 0$.

Comment: Oops, misread the question since the coefficients are complex.  Never mind.

Comment: @Igor, I know that $p(t)$ could be replaced by a rational function on the unit circle, but I don't know what that would do.  There is a paper by Quine that gives a bound on the number of self-intersections for polynomials on the unit circle, but I am unaware of any similar result for rational functions.  

Comment: @Brian: I will ponder...